# SPFx with Office UI Fabric

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, fluentui-react

I am trying to create an SPFx solution with office ui Fabric/Fluent UI. I read somewhere that in higher versions of SPFx with react come with pre installed office ui fabric components with in them. So when I created the default SPFx with yeoman generator it created "office-ui-fabric-react": "7.156.0" in the package.json. but when I tried to import text boxes or buttons, it says that module'@fluentui/react/lib/TextField' not found. My SPFx version is 1.12.0. I created the entry of "@fluentui/react": "7.111.0", in my package.json and error was resolved, but when I run the SPFx it shows the component not found error. my node version is 10.18
My question is, is there any specifc version which I should use to run SPFx with office ui fabric?
is office UI fabric and fluent UI are same? Please guide me about the correct versions so that I can fluent ui controls.

Answer (score 0):

You should use provided Office UI Fabric React package in SPFx 1.12.1, this is the way Microsoft supports now. Yes, Fluent UI and Office UI Fabric are the same.

> Microsoft renamed Office UI Fabric to Fluent UI in early 2020

> The primary Fluent UI React package, @fluentui/react, simply exports components from the office-ui-fabric-react package used in SharePoint Framework projects. At this time, you should continue to use the office-ui-fabric-react package in your SharePoint Framework projects.

More details here: [Office UI Fabric React & Fluent UI React](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/use-fabric-react-components#office-ui-fabric-react--fluent-ui-react)

Answer (score 0):

Fluent UI version 7.178.1, would be supported by SPFX. Try installing the specific version it will solves the problem.